# How to only bindParam if POST values are not empty

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update, user-profile, coalesce

The code I have to update a profile is always updating with the parameters from `POST` in the update statement. Even if they are empty and non null, which means my user gets updated with a lot of empty values. I want the `UPDATE` statement in my SQL statement (I am using PDO) to only change what is set if the value is not empty and also is different to the existing value. Currently, my code I believe IS checking if the value is different to the existing value. I want to use the existing template using `bindParam` if possible but open to other solutions e.g. `if(!isempty)` if you think better!

Here is my update profile page with the`POST` form:

```
<form id="profile_form" action="updateProfile.php" method="post">
                            <input hidden name="userID" value="<?php echo $user; ?>"/>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 " align="center"><img alt="User Pic"
                                                                                src="<?php echo $data['profile_picture']; ?>"
                                                                                class="img-circle img-responsive"
                                style="max-width:30%;max-height:30%;">
                                <p>
                                    <label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" disabled name="userfile"
                                                                                    id="file"> <br/>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_POST['userfile'])){
                                // Configuration - Your Options
                                $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
                                $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
                                $upload_path = './uploads/profile/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

                                $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
                                $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

                                // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
                                if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
                                    die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

                                // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
                                if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
                                    die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

                                // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
                                if(!is_writable($upload_path))
                                    die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

                                // Upload the file to your specified path.
                                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
                                    echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
                                else
                                    echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                                <table class="table table-user-information">
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Username</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="username"
                                                   value= <?php echo $data['username']; ?>>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>First Name</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="firstName"
                                                   value= <?php echo $data['first_name']; ?>></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Last Name</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="lastName"
                                                   value= <?php echo $data['last_name']; ?>>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Date of Birth</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="dob"
                                                   value= <?php echo $data['birthdate']; ?>>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Email</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="email"
                                                   value= <?php echo $data['email']; ?>>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Password</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="password">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--                                    Conditional label based on who you are -->
                                    <?php
                                    if ($data['role_id'] == 2) {
                                        echo "<td>Seller Rating</td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>Buyer Rating</td>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        $stars = round($data['rating'], 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
                                        $diff = $data['rating'] - $stars;
                                        $perc = number_format(($data['rating'] / 5) * 100);
                                        do {
                                            if ($stars == 1 && $diff < 0) {
                                                echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star opacity"></span>';
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>';
                                            }
                                            $stars = $stars - 1;
                                        } while ($stars > 0);
                                        echo "<p>  " . $perc . "% </p>";
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <input class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="edit" type="button" value="Edit">
                                    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" disabled type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </form>


<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('edit');
    var frm = document.getElementById('profile_form');
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
            frm.elements[i].disabled = false;

        }
        frm.elements[0].focus();
    });
</script>
```

Which then passes to `updateProfile.php`:

```
<?php
try {
    require 'dbConnection.php';

    $sql = "UPDATE Users SET
    username = COALESCE(:username,username),
    first_name =COALESCE(:first_name,first_name),
    email =COALESCE(:email,email),
    last_name =COALESCE(:last_name,last_name),
    birthdate =COALESCE(:dob,birthdate),
    passwd =COALESCE(:password,passwd),
    profile_picture = COALESCE(:userfile,profile_picture)
    WHERE user_id =:userID";
    $ins = $db->prepare($sql);

    $hashedPass = sha1($_POST["password"],false);

    $ins->bindParam(':username', $_POST["username"]);
    $ins->bindParam(':email', $_POST["email"]);
    $ins->bindParam(':password', $hashedPass);
    $ins->bindParam(':first_name', $_POST["firstname"]);
    $ins->bindParam(':last_name', $_POST["lastname"]);
    $ins->bindParam(':dob', $_POST["dob"]);
    $ins->bindParam(':userfile', $_POST["userfile"]);
    $ins->bindParam(':userID', $_POST["userID"]);
    $ins->execute();
    header('Location: profile.php');

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: aside: `$hashedPass = sha1($_POST["password"],false);` - don't do this. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` returns the first non-null argument.  So if you want to keep your code working the same way you can change each `bindParam` call to:

```
$ins->bindParam(':username', $_POST["username"] ?: null);
```

So any "false" value ('', 0, etc.) gets sent to the DB as null.

If you want to conditionally call `bindParam` you'll also need to conditionally build your SQL.  The bound parameters must line up with the parameters defined in SQL.  At that point you're dynamically building a query string, which gets ugly quickly.

However, I think this is a bad solution and the code can be written better.  For example, if you're taking a form POST, why would there be empty values for previously set data?  I would pre-fill the form on load with the current data.  Also consider switching to a query builder or ORM so only modified fields are put into the query.

Comment: Sorry this isn't working. I am trying to add back a value for example first name which was previously blank. When I put an input into the text field and click submit, this new value is not in the database (the field first name was previously blank).

Comment: Try `empty($_POST["username"]) ? null : $_POST["username"]`

Comment: Sorry how will this `bindParam` like `:username` conditionally?

Comment: I made an edit: If you want to conditionally call `bindParam` you'll also need to conditionally build your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. The `COALESCE` statement was a distraction. I used an array to build up the SQL as @Matt S mentions.

Here is code for `updateProfile.php`.

Also, there is no need to use `bindParam` with PDO.:

```
<?php
try {
    require 'dbConnection.php';

    $sql = "UPDATE Users SET ";

    $username = "";
    $firstName = "";
    $lastName = "";
    $dob = "";
    $userfile = "";
    $email = "";
    $hashedPass = "";

    if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $hashedPass = sha1($_POST["password"], false);
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
        $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["lastName"])) {
        $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["dob"])) {
        $dob = $_POST["dob"];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["userfile"])) {
        $userfile = $_POST["userfile"];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    $userID = $_POST['userID'];

    $updates = array();

    if ($username != "") {
        $updates[] = "username='$username'";
    }
    if ($firstName != "") {
        $updates[] = "first_name='$firstName'";
    }
    if ($lastName != "") {
        $updates[] = "last_name='$lastName'";
    }
    if ($email != "") {
        $updates[] = "email='$email'";
    }
    if ($dob != "") {
        $updates[] = "birthdate='$dob'";
    }
    if ($userfile != "") {

        $updates[] = "profile_picture='$userfile'";
    }
    if ($hashedPass != "") {
        $updates[] = "passwd='$hashedPass'";
    }

    if (count($updates) > 0) {
        $sql .= implode(', ', $updates) . " WHERE user_id='$userID'";
    }
//    Prepare query
    $updatequery = $db->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $updatequery->execute();

    header('Location: profile.php');

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```